# Multiple questions about re-roll ability interactions with critical rolls

Tags: discussion, duplicates

These are all questions asking about re-roll abilites (such as the lucky feat) and critical successes or failures.

- [Can Lucky be used on an attack roll if the roll is a 'Nat 1'?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123496/9625) (Today; Already closed as a duplicate)
- [When exactly is the outcome of a roll determined?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122760/9625) (From 12 days ago)
- [Do reroll and dice-adding abilities work on critical hits and critical failures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/69811/9625) (From 2 years ago)

All of the answers seem to be the same, with differences in length and substance.

**Should these questions be closed and rolled together, and if so how?**

Comment: Deleted my comment as "second question" would now be misleading.

Answer (score 10):

### Duplicates are about duplicate *questions*, not duplicate answers

Yes, some questions will have the same answers: for example, \$2+2=4\$, \$2^2=4\$, \$6-2=4\$. They are not duplicates *merely* because of that.

They *might* be duplicates if the questions are about different specific examples that are symptomatic of a more general problem.

To my mind, these questions do not obviously meet these criteria: each OP had a different problem - *one* of the solutions to which may be common to all of them but remember the stack embraces a plurality of answers. Other solutions may be unique to the specific circumstances and these can be lost by prematurely marking posts as duplicates.

Comment: I think this is what I was trying to say in my now deleted answer to this question.

Comment: Fair. They just seemed to be tackling the same *problem,* but I see now they're different enough in the asking.

Answer (score 2):

## Close the dupes as dupes

It's the same approach as always. The questions are clearly duplicates, the body text is essentially the same. The first one is a particular case of the other two, but the second (which is mine, just to be clear) and third are the same, with the exception that I include Death Saving Throws as an example besides the Nat 1s and Nat 20s. The third question clearly states "My issue is understanding the concept "Before the outcome is determined".", which is exactly what I ask about in my own.

## Which one remains?

I vote for my own, even though it was asked way more recently. My reasoning is:

- The 3rd question also asks about Portent and Bardic Inspiration. Portent is not **before the outcome**, but **before the roll**, so it's a completely different question. This part of the question seems to be ignored by the answers, and I would say if it is important the question should be closed as too broad as it's two questions in one.
- More importantly, [Vigil's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/122761/43856) to my question has more backing up from actual rulebooks (citing the fundamental rules of D&D and quoting Illusory Step, which are vaguely mentioned in [Derek's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/69813/43856), which is accepted in the original question).

The question itself can be improved, but I already think it states a single problem better than the original one, and I certainly think the answer is better than the answers in the original question. For both these reasons I'd say close the "original" question as a duplicate.